# ASP.Net Ajax UpdatePanel to be loaded only after the page is ready

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I am using `ASP.Net AJAX` `UpdatePanel` to load the right part of the page.

As that part will take some time to load, I would like to load it after the other parts of the page is loaded.

I can use either normal `AJAX` or `ASP.Net AJAX` but I chose to use the latter as I want to try it out.

I found out that my `UpdatePanel` is always loaded.

I want it to be loaded only after the page is ready.

Some says to use the timer, some says to use some javascript.

But I still can't get it done.

So, these are my 2 obstacles, to stop loading when the page starts and to start loading when the page is ready

Comment: take a look here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/116273/A-Generic-Way-to-Delay-load-Lazy-load-Any-Number-o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var currentItemID=$('#<%= labcurrentItemID.ClientID %>').html();
    if (currentItemID != null) {
        $(document).ready(function () { 
            $('#main_container').load('/Custom/Going%20Places/PopularRelatedArticle.aspx?currentID=' + currentItemID);
        });
    }
    else {
        $(document).ready(function () { 
            $('#main_container').load('/Custom/Going%20Places/PopularRelatedArticle.aspx?currentID={7F0811A7-D484-4675-8A23-0AEB235B9B5F}');
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you enable and disable on page events? for example. try in Page_PreLoad event, set the update panel's enable property to False. While in Page_LoadComplete event, set it back to enabled = true

Answer (score 0):

UpdatePanels use Ajax to update, not on first load.

If you want it to load quickly on first load, avoid any expensive processing, database calls on load. Put them in an

```
if(IsPostBack)
{
  //your long processing
}
```

Now use an [AsyncPostBackTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.asyncpostbacktrigger.aspx) to make your updatePanel postback.

Answer (score 0):

try with this code ( Conditional Mode + Update Method)

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="YourIdPanel" UpdateMode="Conditional"                                  runat="server">


//In order to force loading
YourIdPanel.Update();
```

Comment: And how do you know when the page load is complete and run that `YourIPanel.Update();`